# Is it possible to set an environment variable in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am building a web application that has a whitelabel option.

The whitelabel option offers all of the same functionality of the core website but is based off a different domain. When on that domain, a number of different templates and rules are applied to the site to account for the whitelabel features.

I would like to run almost all of my features on both the core domain and the whitelabel domain. How can I set an environment variable in Cucumber (ideally via the command line) so that I can rerun these critical tests based off the new domain?

Comment: Cucumber has before and after hooks check http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/cucumber-more-advanced/ for more info. Is it helpful?

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I didn't know this but together with @alistairH's answer this gives me what I need - ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via the command line like this:

```
bundle exec cucumber features DOMAIN=somedomain.local
```

You can then access this in ruby, for example in your env.rb file, like this:

```
if ENV['DOMAIN']
  # set features to run against the appropriate domain
end
```

Comment: Thank you. As a follow up question do you know how to setup a rake task to run multiple sets of tests with different initialisations?

Comment: I've done something similar by just setting up two separate rake tasks, and then a third task that just runs the other two e.g. task :cucumber => ['cucumber:sometests', 'cucumber:somemoretests']. Not entirely happy with this though as the second set never run if any of the first set fail.